# Tag all rows with the same values in Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Let's say I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "test_ids" (
   var1 TEXT,
   var2 TEXT,
   var3 TEXT,
   time INT
);

INSERT INTO "test_ids" VALUES
('d1', 'i1', 'f1', 1),
('d2', 'i1', 'f1', 2),
('d2', 'i2', 'f1', 3),
('d1', 'i1', 'f2', 4),
('d3', 'i3', 'f3', 1),
('d3', 'i4', 'f3', 2),
('d3', 'i5', 'f3', 3),
('d3', 'i3', 'f4', 4),
('d4', 'i1', 'f5', 5);
```

There is a many-many-many relationship between the columns var1, var2, var3 with each combination of them being stored on a row with the time that this combination was first observed.

However, there's is a 1 to many relationship between a user and a variable.  That is, one variable (be it `var1`, `var2` or `var3`) can only ever be observed by one user.

I want to produce a table that applies a unique user_id to all rows that we work out belong to one user - for example, all rows with:

- `d1`
- Any `var2` or `var3` that's ever been observed alongside `d1`
- Any `var3` that's ever been observed alongside any of those `var2`s with a different `var1`
- Any `var2` that's ever been observed alongside any of those `var3`s with a different `var1`
- Any other `var1` that's ever been observed alongside any of those `var2`s or `var3`s

In this example, the output would be:

```
 user | var1 | var2 | var3 | time 
------+------+------+------+------
 u1   | d1   | i1   | f1   |    1
 u1   | d2   | i1   | f1   |    2
 u1   | d2   | i2   | f1   |    3
 u1   | d1   | i1   | f2   |    4
 u2   | d3   | i3   | f3   |    1
 u2   | d3   | i4   | f3   |    2
 u2   | d3   | i5   | f3   |    3
 u2   | d3   | i3   | f4   |    4
 u1   | d4   | i1   | f5   |    5
```

Don't worry about how to make the user ID unique - I can do that part.  I'm struggling to work out the recursive joining of IDs, however.

Comment: did you try using the `row_number()` function?

Comment: Thank you, @vkp - yes.  That can solve the first of those bullet points.  However, I'm getting tied up when trying to sort out the many-many-many relationship between all variables.  If you have a code example to solve that with `ROW_NUMBER()`, I'd love to see it!

Comment: as i know, it is not possible with `row_number()` function

Comment: @Serenthia
I don't understand where the user field coming from. How would you know that u1 is related to d1, i1, f1?
Is it in another table?
Let's make the "manual" example clearer and then maybe we can find a solution.

Comment: @Gluz I will just use any var1 from the final set - it is impossible for one var1 to be present in more than one set, so this will be a unique identifier. This isn't my issue - I haven't found a way to group all the var1s/var2s/var3s that appear for one user in order to tag them all with the same user ID - ie. Recognise that lines 1,2,3,4 and 9 are all one user, while 5,6,7,8 are another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this following case is possible:

```
d1, i1, f1
d1, i2, f2
d2, i2, f3,
d3, i3, f3
```

And assuming you would like to attribute all of these rows to same user, then my answer is you can't. In some, more mature, DBs there is a tree query but even this type of query won't work here.
If it is only a theoretical question then you can stop here, if you would a practical answer then I would either run an algorithm with some kind of programming language or, better (at least performance wise), implement a solution in the operational system that adds this rows to the DB:
Every time a new row enters, it will check if one of the keys in already attributes to a user, if it is, it keeps the user id, if not, assign new user id.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this out.  I think you're right, and so have actually ended up writing this in Scala :)